# How do I keep the rotation of a player when teleporting them?

Tags: minecraft

I made a cannon that shoots you in the sky and once you can't see anything below you, and when you're around 400 y or so, it'll teleport you to another place in the sky where you fall down and end up on sky islands. It would be unnoticeable except the hand moves when it changes your direction. So is there a way to keep the rotation data that you were at before you were teleported or any way to lock the player in a certain rotation until they're teleported?

Comment: What are you using to achieve this? Are you making Bukkit plugin or a client mod?

Comment: I'm just using command blocks to spawn in tnt under the player. As far as I can tell so far, changing the player direction requires teleporting them which would get rid of the momentum from the tnt.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this thing:

```
Player p;
Location loc = new location(x, y, z);
loc.setPitch(p.getLocation().getPitch());
loc.setYaw(p.getLocation().getYaw());
```

But this was not tested yet.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Yaw, and the Pitch the player is looking at. The yaw is the rotation on the y-axis, and when you look straight North it is set to 0. The pitch is the up-down-axis, and when you look straight ahead, it is set to 0.
You can see the Pitch and Yaw, if you do F3, in-game.